# Error when I try to make onclicklistetener

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, onclicklistener

I tried to make the onclicklistener function but I get an error on onBindViewHolder

I tried to make a cardview that can be clicked based on the id_daftar, and the database that I use is on the webserver

this is my adapter

```
import...

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public DataAdapter (ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android){
        this.android = android;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row,parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder,final int position) {
        holder.tv_nama_pengusaha.setText(android.get(position).getNama_pengusaha());
        holder.tv_nama_usaha.setText(android.get(position).getNama_usaha());
        holder.tv_alamat.setText(android.get(position).getAlamat());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("nama_usaha", android.get(position).getNama_usaha());
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView tv_nama_pengusaha, tv_nama_usaha, tv_alamat, tv_id_daftar, tv_rt,
                tv_rw, tv_desa, tv_kecamatan, tv_kategori;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // implement onClick
            tv_nama_pengusaha = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nama_pengusaha);
            tv_nama_usaha = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nama_usaha);
            tv_alamat = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_alamat);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my DetailActivity

```
import...

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView detailData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        detailData = findViewById(R.id.tv_nama_usaha);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String content = i.getStringExtra("nama_usaha");

        detailData.setText(content);
        detailData.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

this is the error i got

[image]

can someone explain what is the error mean and the solution?

Comment: That error means that one of your `holder`'s `TextView`s is null when you call `setText()` on it. That would indicate, ultimately, that at least one of the `<TextView>`s with ID `tv_nama_pengusaha`, `tv_nama_usaha`, or `tv_alamat` is not in the current `card_row` layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if all TextViews that are found in the `R.layout.card_row` exist and that they have the correct IDs:

```
tv_nama_pengusaha

tv_nama_usaha

tv_alamat
```